# Eventbrite OAUTH2 login on windows store apps keep me get BAD REQUEST

Tags: windows-8, oauth-2.0, eventbrite

I got problem on oauth2 handshake, as the eventbrite documentation is not very clear.
http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/oauth2/ -> number 4

what i currently do is like this

WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/token");

```
        string URLEncoded = "code=" + token + "&client_secret=" + APISecret + "&client_id=" + APIKey + "&grant_type=authorization_code";

        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";         
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(URLEncoded);
        Stream os = null;
        try
        {
            os = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
           WebResponse response = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();            
            os = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(os);

            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            string err = ex.ToString();

        }
        finally
        {
            if (os != null)
            {
                os.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Can someone give tips on this? i keep getting BAD REQUEST as a result. Thank you

edited : the response say : code is invalid or expired

I know its clear, but i already implement and get the token to exchange, use Secret API key and API Key to get it, but how come its invalid/expired?